# Very long delay when running C# unit test in VS2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I have a very long delay (about 1 minute! even more) when running unit test in VS2015. When running even a single test, I see the progress bar in the top of the "Test Explorer", it flows for about a minute, and then I get the test result. The reported test runtime is as expected - very small, few milliseconds.

My question is - how can I debug this? How can I see what is going on in this minute before the test actually starts to run?

Comment: it s not clear if you are actually debugging test and your very first breakpoint hits after a minute or if you are only running the test. In second case to debug this you need to breakpoint and debug run test ;)

Comment: Are you running a universal Windows app unit test?

Comment: I have run in to a similar issue on a random basis. It seems to be a bug. Most of the time, the tests run very fast (in milliseconds), but then every once in a while it seems to get hung on something. Doesn't matter if I am running 1 test or 50. Just a huge pause, sometimes several minutes waiting for the test run to start. Then once the tests start running they are fast. Usually restarting Visual Studio will clear it up...for a while. Very annoying. Still happens in Update 2.

Comment: I get the same problem, but it is very sporadic. Sometimes the test execution starts very quickly but sometimes the same test takes over a minute to start executing. This can be seen by putting a breakpoint on the first line of the test.

Comment: I have the same problem with .net core project. The tests execution time are very fast but all the setup takes forever 2minutes. That is too long for TDD

Comment: You can also try to run in parallel for several tests. It may not be the core of the problem but maybe it would help

Comment: I'm having this exact issue in one of our solutions. After clicking on "Run All", it takes about 20 seconds for the incremental build to finish, but then it takes UP TO 3 MINUTES for the tests to actually start running! This is making me really mad right now.

Answer (score 4):

A minute is quite a long time for *nothing* to be happening.  There is a lot of startup processing that has to happen before any tests are run (all of the assemblies and their dependencies need to be loaded for example).  This hit is generally the same if you're running a single test or running all of the tests in your suite.

If you look in the "Tests" output window, you'll get a better idea of what's actually going on and the actual amount of time taken to run the tests.  For example on mine, running one test shows a similar overhead to running 49 tests..

> ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:01.0416253) ==========
>
> ========== Run test finished: 49 run (0:00:01.9156121) ==========

There are various things that can slow down assembly loading, such as static constructors.  I would tend to start off by creating a fresh test project with no dependencies to verify that it doesn't exhibit the same long delay issue so that you know it's not just your machine.  Then I'd add in the dependencies of your existing test project, one dependency at a time to see if adding a particular dependency triggers the delay...  Then I would look at that project to see if there's anything going on, such as static constructors that attempt to connect to a database / establish network connections.

It may also be worth trying to debug your tests, but making sure that you've got  Break When Exceptions are thrown turned on (if it is something like a failed database connection that's causing the slow down there's a good chance an exception might be thrown as part of that process).

Comment: Is there a way to get a good log of the actions being performed during this time? I don't see anything on my test output window yet it runs for ~3 minutes before starting to execute the tests.